# Logging into wordpress adds a subdirectory to the URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently created a wordpress theme, and wanted to have my own login area on the main page. The code I'm using is below, but for some reason it doesn't quite work. It allows me to log in, but when I do I'm redirected to example.com/wordpress/wordpress/ instead of example.com/wordpress/ and I can't figure out where the extra subdirectory is coming from. The code 'works' because if I manually change the URL after getting 404'd I'm logged in, but I can't figure out why it's doing that in the first place.

```
<?php $args = array(
        'echo'           => false,
        'redirect'       => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
        'form_id'        => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false
    );
        wp_login_form( $args );  

    echo '<form name="' . $args['form_id'] . '" id="' . $args['form_id'] . '" action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">';
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo '<input type="text" name="log" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ) . '" class="input" value="' . esc_attr( $args['value_username'] ) . '" size="12" />'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<input type="password" name="pwd" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_password'] ) . '" class="input" value="" size="12" />'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ) . '" class="button-primary" value="' . esc_attr( $args['label_log_in'] ) . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="' . esc_url( $args['redirect'] ) . '" />'; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have WordPress installed to `http://www.example.com/wordpress`. The problem in your code is the `redirect` parameter of your `$args` array. You have:

`'redirect'       => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),`

The `site_url` function will return the base URL that you have configured in WordPress, in this case `http://www.example.com/wordpress`, and to the end of that it will add to it the content of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which in this case is `/wordpress`, so you end up with `http://www.example.com/wordpress/wordpress`.

To solve this issue the parameter you want to pass to `redirect` is whatever URL underneath the `/wordpress` directory you want to redirect to. Example:

`'redirect'       => site_url( '/some-example-page/' ),`

will redirect to `http://www.example.com/wordpress/some-example-page/`, and

`'redirect'       => site_url(),`

will redirect to the base of your WordPress installation, `http://www.example.com/wordpress`.

If you remove the `redirect` parameter from your `$args` array, the default value of `redirect` will be whatever page the function was called from.

See [site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [wp_login_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) on the WordPress Codex for more information on the functions, and [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730834/1832106) for how `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` works. I think you're using the example from the WordPress Codex page about `wp_login_form` and the redirect arguments provided on that page will cause this behavior if WordPress isn't installed to the root of the domain.