# execute code before redirect php

Tags: php, redirect

I want to write some information in a txt file (user name, user mail and ip address) and then redirect to another html file. If I try to redirect nothing appears in the text file. But if I don't redirect to an html file the php script is working correctly. What am I missing?

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt1 = file_get_contents("newfile.txt");
$ip = get_client_ip_server();
$txt2 = $_COOKIE["userName"] ."\t" .$_COOKIE["userEmail"]." \t".$ip. "\r\n";
$txt3 = $txt1 . $txt2;
fwrite($myfile, $txt3);
fclose($myfile);
die();
header( "HTTP/1.0 302 Found" );
header( "Status: 302" ); # this is for chrome compliance
header( "Location: general.html" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
// Function to get the client ip address
function get_client_ip_server() {
$ipaddress = '';
      if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress =getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `die();` is before header so header never happens. Put the die after header.

Comment: What @Fred-ii- said :)

Comment: This is a joke, right?

Comment: @trincot I always like a good chuckle myself ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- AMAZING ALWAYS.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Are you creating troll accounts again? :P

Comment: @Flosculus Errr.. I don't understand what you mean. I only have one account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok someone posted an answer, so I will also.

`die();` is before header so header never happens. Put the die after header.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

---

**Edit:**

After a successful test of your code and my suggestion to move `die();` after header; make sure that the cookies are indeed set/not empty and you (may) need to remove `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` from `header( "Location: general.html" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );`

Using `header( "Location: general.html" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );` failed for me to redirect to `general.html` and removing `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` did redirect to `general.html`.

References:

- [Check if a PHP cookie exists and if not set its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738593/check-if-a-php-cookie-exists-and-if-not-set-its-value)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

Using this as a test:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt1 = file_get_contents("newfile.txt");
$ip = get_client_ip_server();
// $txt2 = $_COOKIE["userName"] ."\t" .$_COOKIE["userEmail"]." \t".$ip. "\r\n";

$txt2 = "Username cookie"  ."\t" . " Email cookie " ." \t".$ip. "\r\n";

$txt3 = $txt1 . $txt2;
fwrite($myfile, $txt3);
fclose($myfile);

header( "HTTP/1.0 302 Found" );
header( "Status: 302" ); # this is for chrome compliance

header( "Location: general.html");
// header( "Location: general.html" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );

die();

// Function to get the client ip address
function get_client_ip_server() {
$ipaddress = '';
      if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress =getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
}
?>
```

Yielded: (numbers are examples only)

```
Username cookie  Email cookie   11.22.33.44

Username cookie  Email cookie   11.22.33.44

Username cookie  Email cookie   11.22.33.44
```

---

About `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

> 'REQUEST_URI'
>       The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

See also:

- [what is the difference between $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_GET['q']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730798/what-is-the-difference-between-serverrequest-uri-and-getq)

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit #2:**

After testing something I think is preventing your redirection, is that your file may have been saved as UTF-8 with BOM (byte order mark) and if this is the case, then you are outputting before header. Error reporting will notify you of that.

Either you save that file as ANSI, or UTF-8 without BOM.

Consult:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Yeah `die` After you have sent the visitor their way. Don't `die()` with the job half done ;) And if at all you wish to `die()` before that then delegate that task to someone else named `JavaScript`. Though you don't need to `die()` at all. Your code is just fine without it

Comment: any day you got my support :)

Comment: @Andrew Cheers Andrew

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your help. But the text file remains blank even if I move the die().

Comment: @IdreesSamim You're welcome. Give me a few minutes. I'll go to my other machine and test it.

Comment: @IdreesSamim Reload my answer and look under **Edit**.

Comment: @IdreesSamim another reason why your redirection may not be working is that you may be outputting before header. Reload my answer again, I've made another edit and go over it carefully. Use error reporting as shown in there also. Those are the conclusions I've come to. There isn't anything else I can add to my answer here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you my error was in another part of my code and not in the php file.

Comment: @IdreesSamim You're welcome. Glad to see it was resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

The `die` is before the redirect, you should put it after the header redirection ;)