# PHP URL redirect error

Tags: php

I am trying to write a simple PHP URL redirect script but it's not working.

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
header('Location: $_GET['link']');    
    }else{
        echo 'invalid link';
    }
?>
```

If I access the script as http://www.example.com/redirect.php, then it goes into else loop and I get output as 'invalid link' in the browser.

But if I access it as https://www.example.com/redirect.php?link=https://www.google.com then I get HTTP error 500. Ideally page should be redirected to https://www.google.com

I am new to PHP and unable to figure it out, any help please?

Comment: just saw php error log "[21-Oct-2017 05:53:48 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'link' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in redirect.php on line 4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
    header("Location: {$_GET[link]}");    
}else{
    echo 'invalid link';
}
```

`'` single quotes cannot escape `variables` in php you need to use `"` double quotes for that. And there is not need to enclose the index with quotes when being used inside a string.  And as for the `{}` curly brackets that I am using look into [Complex Curly Brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Also, as you were doing it with `'Location: $_GET['link']'` there was another problem with that, that the string was starting from `'Location:` but was ending at `$_GET['` because it was closing the single quotes there and was causing an error too.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also noticed it after few mins but you were really quick to answer.

Comment: SO requires 10 mins wait before accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are giving invalid string matching string

```
if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
header('Location:'.$_GET['link']);    
    }else{
        echo 'invalid link';
    }
```

or this method also works

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

see the difference $_GET['link'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

[what is the difference between $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_GET['q']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730798/what-is-the-difference-between-serverrequest-uri-and-getq)

Comment: Thanks for showing alternative way by using $_SERVER. BTW, which is the better, secure and faster way to go.

Comment: Security and speed wise there is no difference as the alternative method only uses another variable. But it will not provide the same result. It will work for `https://www.example.com/redirect.php?link=test.php` but not for `https://www.example.com/redirect.php?link=https://www.google.com`

Comment: Also, your first method have a syntax error, `'Location:' $_GET['link']` should be `'Location:' . $_GET['link']`

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = !empty($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] : '';
if ($url){
    header('Location:' . $url);
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'invalid link';
}
```